# C++ Library/Class to create simple video files out of memory bitmap array

Tags: c++, windows, video

I have written an academic simulation software. The simulation results are stored in a 2D memory array of 1byte values (mapped to 256 colors).

I need to write a class which reads the array in determined intervals and creates a video file out of it. The format is not important (as long as it is popular).

Is there a C++ wrapper class (over windows APIs) or library which can easily do this for me?

Comment: I also think libx264 can do this. And it generates a very high resolution video to boot.

Comment: Have you considered saving your images out to a set of files (e.g. 001.bmp, 002.bmp, 003.bmp....) then launch ffmpeg in the background to encode the entire directory of files into a single movie file.  Otherwise, libavcodec and libavformat (which come with ffmpeg source) could be useful. Another option: Save as animated GIF using GDI+.  You have to create the pallete yourself and feed that into the API for best results.  This will produce a big file if you have lots of frames.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution is to use the "Video for Windows API". This set of functions is built into Windows and allows you to create AVI files with various video codecs from a series of bitmaps. You can optionally record audio with it as well. Here is a link to a sample project which demonstrates how to use it:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4169/A-simple-interface-to-the-Video-for-Windows-API-fo

The functions are very high level and don't require a wrapper to use them. At the simplest level you will be calling:

```
AVIFileOpen();
AVIFileCreateStream();
AVIStreamWriteData(); // repeat for each frame
AVIStreamRelease();
AVIFileRelease();
```

You can pass each frame as a DIB (device independent bitmap) to the stream and it will create video from your individual frames.

The API documentation is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756804(v=vs.85).aspx